# Dereferencing hashes of hashes in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I'm trying to collect the values that I store in a hash of hashes, but I'm kinda confused in how perl does that. So, I create my hash of hashes as follows:

```
 my %hash;
 my @items;

 #... some code missing here, generally I'm just populating the @items list 
 #with $currentitem items

 while (<FILE>) { #read the file

         ($a, $b) = split(/\s+/,$_,-1);
         $hash{$currentitem} => {$a => $b};
         print $hash{$currentitem}{$a} . "\n";#this is a test and it works
}
```

The above code seems to work. Now, to the point: I have an array @items, which keeps the $currentitem values. And I want to do something like this:

```
@test = keys %hash{ $items[$num] };
```

So that I can get all the key/value pairs for a specific item. I've tried the line of code above, as well as

```
 while ( ($key, $value) = each( $hash{$items[$num]} ) ) {

      print "$key, $value\n";
 }
```

I've even tried to populate  the hash as follows:

```
$host{ "$currentcustomer" }{"$a"} => "$b";
```

Which seems to be more correct according to the various online sources I've met. But still, I can't access the data inside that hash... Any ideas?

Comment: Offtopic. `$hash{$currentitem} => {$a => $b};` - did you mean "=" instead of first "=>"?

Comment: @Dallyaylaen, that's not the only problem with that statement.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am confused by you saying that this works:

```
$hash{$currentitem} => {$a => $b};
```

That shouldn't work (and doesn't work for me).  The `=>` operator is a special kind of comma, not an assignment (see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html)).  In addition, the construct on the right makes a new anonymous hash.  Using that, a new anonymous hash would overwrite the old one for each element you tried to add.  You would only ever have one element for each `$currentitem`.

Here is what you want for assignment:

```
$hash{$currentitem}{$a} = $b;
```

And here is how to get the keys:

```
keys %{ $hash{ $items[$num] } };
```

I suggest reading up on [Perl references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) to get a better handle on this.  The syntax can be a bit tricky at first.

Comment: Indeed this solved my problem. And yes, "=>" doesn't work for me either. But for some weird reason, perl swallows it silently sometimes. Maybe cygwin is the problem??? No idea, but when i tested on my debian it didn't work... :S

Comment: `$hash{$currentitem} => {$a => $b};` is actually a syntactically valid statement.  It just doesn't do anything.  Make sure you always `use warnings;` to catch problems like this.

Answer (score 1):

Long answer is in [perldoc perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

Short answer is:

```
keys %{ $expr_producing_hash_ref };
```

In your case I believe it's

```
keys %{ $hash{$items[$num]} };
```